# Why does the same TeX file generate PDF file with different page margins?

Tags: miktex, texmaker

I installed MiKTeX and Texmaker on office and personal computers, but the two computers generate different top page margins `.pdf` file using the same `.tex` file?

The office computer generates the right one, but my personal computer generates the wrong one with bigger top page margin. The MiKTeX version of office computer is older. Maybe it is related with some packages, but I'm not sure which one to be updated.

How could I solve the problems?

EDIT: added code (begin of the `tex` file) from comment to question:

```
\documentclass[journal]{IEEEtran} 
\usepackage{graphicx} 
\usepackage{url} 
\usepackage{amsmath} 
\interdisplaylinepenalty=2500 
\usepackage[english]{babel} 
\usepackage{array} 
%\usepackage{flushend} 
\hyphenation{industrial electronics IEEEtran} 
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames]{color} \usepackage[font=footnotesize,caption=false,farskip=0mm,captionskip=0mm,nearskip‌​=0mm]{subfig}
```

Comment: Update both distributions to the newest ones and see if it helps. (I don't think it has got anything to do with Texmaker; that's just an editor.)

Comment: Did you specify the paper size in the `\documentclass` directive or in `\usepackage[…]{geometry}`? Systems can be set up with different defaults depending on preferences set during install.

Comment: If not specified, `latex` uses a predefined papersize which is stored in some config file during installation. Please check if there is a difference, on using `letter` and one `a4`.

Comment: MikteX sets default paper size in the Options Menu, General tab.

Comment: Thank you all. I checked the tex file, it is exactly the same. Then, I added \listfiles, and found there is a different packages version. The right one is :url.sty 2006/04/12 ver 3.3 Verb mode for urls, etc. The wrong one is :url.sty 2013/09/16 ver 3.4 Verb mode for urls, etc. Does this make sense?\\ I also find an interesting phenomenon, although the top page margin is different, the total pages are the same, and the content on each page is also exactly the same. The difference is just the top and left margin a little bigger making it look weird. Could you figure out what's the reason?Thanks.

Comment: I also checked the papersize setting, they are both A4(A4 size). It really puzzles me, and brings much inconvenience as I have to generate the right .pdf file using my office computer. Please help me. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for helping me. Problems have been solved. I just changed the default page size A4(A4 size) to Letter, then backed to the default page size A4(A4 size). It was weird, wasn't it? As I didn't change any other things, just back to the default. Any way, problems have been solved, so I write it down here, which may be helpful to the ones who meet the same problems.